# Построение графика в делфи

Tags: delphi

Я работаю над курсовой на тему решения уравнения

```
cos(x) - (4 * x) + 1 = 0
```

Я написал программу для решения.

Как построить на её основе график?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавив компонент TChart и выбрав в настройках нужный тип, в подходящем обработчике отрисовать график.

```
begin
    OurGraph.Clear;
    for i := 0 to 100 do
    begin
        OurGraph.AddXY(...);
    end;
end;
```

Как-то так.